# How can i fix selenium wrong permission error?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.9

I downloaded selenium and chrome driver but when i run

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/NahuApple/webDriver")
driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
time.sleep(5)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

I get this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'webDriver' executable may have wrong permissions?
```

how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are providing path to a folder, so use the full path to ChromeDriver.exe:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/Users/NahuApple/webDriver/chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: I tried it and got this error 

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH

thanks for the help